# How to connect to a GKE service from GCE using internal IPs

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an Nginx service deployed in GKE with a NodePort exposed and i want to connect it from my Compute Engine instances through internal IP address only. When i try to connect to the Nginx with the cluster IP i only receive Timeout.

I think that clusterIP is only reachable inside a cluster but when i activated the NodePort might be works.

I am not know well the difference between NodePort and ClusterIP.

Comment: ClusterIP is reachable only inside cluster. If you want to access it from outside you need to use `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`. Example with `NodePort` you have in Kubernetes Documentation - [Use a Service to Access an Application in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/). You can use curl for tests. `curl http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>` Please keep in mind that you also need to configure Firewall and use proper node ip. If you could share your configuration (without PII/sensitive data) it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

You can expose your application outside cluster using [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer). `ClusterIP` allows connection only inside the cluster and it's default [Service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

- ClusterIP:

> Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType

- NodePort:

> Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :.

- LoadBalancer

> Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

In short, when you are using `NodePort` you need to use `NodePublicIP:NodePort`. When you are using `LoadBalancer` it will create `Network LB` with `ExternalIP`.

In your GKE cluster you have something called [VPC - Virtual Private Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview) which provides networking for your cloud-based resources and services that is global, scalable, and flexible.

### Solution

**Using VPC-Native CLuster**
Wit [VPC-native clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips) you'll be able to reach to Pod's IPs directly. You will need to create `subnet` in order to do it. Full guide can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips)

**Using VPC Peering**
If you would like to connect from 2 different projects in GKE, you will need to use [VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

**Access from outside the cluster using NodePort**

If you would like to reach your nginx service from outside you can use `NodeIP:NodePort`.
`NodeExternalIP` (keep in mind that this node must have application pod on it. If you have 3 nodes and only 1 application replica, you must use `NodeExternalIP` where this pod was deployed. Another node, you need to allow `NodePort` access on `Firewall`.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION             INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     OS-IMAGE                             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-faec7b51-n5hm   Ready    <none>   3h23m   v1.17.14-gke.1600   10.128.0.26   23.236.50.249   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.19.150+        docker://19.3.6

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx        NodePort    10.8.9.10    <none>        80:30785/TCP   39m

$ curl 23.236.50.249:30785
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster IP address is only accessible within cluster; so that's why it is giving timeout message. Nodeport use to expose a port on Public IP of every node of cluster; so it may work.